# MongoDB regex multiple query with $and

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm having problem to achieve this.

I have this piece of code which I had tested in Rock Mongo and it works fine.

```
array(
    'TEST' => 
    array( '$in' => 
        array( new MongoRegex('/^(?!TESTVALUE)/$ig'))
         )
     )
```

Above piece of code return me all documents which haven't value "TESTVALUE" for the key "TEST".

Now what I want to achieve?

First I don't know how to write piece of code to fetch all documents which haven't values "TESTVALUE" & "SECONDVALUE" for the key "TEST".

That will be something like this:

```
array(
    'TEST' => 
    array( '$in' => 
        array( new MongoRegex('/^(?!TESTVALUE)/$ig'),new MongoRegex('/^(?!SECONDVALUE)/$ig') )
        )
     )
```

And also I will need above piece of code written in PHP.

Any kind of help or suggestions is welcome and will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use $in like that, but this should work:

```
'TEST' => array('$and' => array(
    array('$regex' => new MongoRegex('/^(?!TESTVALUE)/$ig'),
    array('$regex' => new MongoRegex('/^(?!TESTVALUE)/$ig')))
```

something to that effect (untested)

Comment: That doesn't work, but I see that you wrote untested. 
If I try to do something with this I'll tell you.

Comment: Yeah basically what I'm getting at is that you have to compare against each regex - or figure out how to write them into one (maybe with the | operator). $in expects explicit values

Comment: I'm giving up for today. I really don't have ideas anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries and your description seem to contradict each other. If you want a query for all documents which don't have some string as the field value, why are you using regexes? Do you not want the value to be a substring of the field value? If you just want to do a query like "find documents where the value of the `TEST` field is not "X" or "Y", use `$nin` ("not in"):

```
db.collection.find({ "TEST" : { "$nin" : ["X", "Y"] } })
```

If the field should match multiple regexes, then either combine them into a single regex or combine the conditions with `$and`.